# c++ rand() strange behavior

Tags: c++, random

I see a very strange behavior when using rand() in c++. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define N 10
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(true) {
        int i = N * ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        //std::cout << i << std::endl;  // If there is any code here, everything goes fine.
        if (i == N) {
            std::cout << "i " << i << " should never happen" << std::endl;
        } else {  
            std::cout << ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
i 10 should never happen
i 10 should never happen
i 10 should never happen
...
```

It really doesn't make sense to me because I think i will never ever be 10.
The strange thing is that it works perfectly fine if I try any of the following:

- I use debugger and step trace the code, the value of i is random in
  the watch.
- I add code like sdt:cout as I shown in the comment of my code.
- I use (RAND_MAX + 1.0) instead of (RAND_MAX).

**My compiler is mingw32-g++.exe (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1.**

This really confuses me, could anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected:

> The `rand()` function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX` inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, `RAND_MAX`]).
>
> —[man rand(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

So `rand() / RAND_MAX` *can* be 1 because the range is inclusive. Your fix with `RAND_MAX + 1` is usually the option that is taken.

That being said, there are better options to generate random numbers in a range that will yield a uniform distribution.

Comment: If this is the case, how do you explain this "when I put a line of cout to print the value, I never see i 10 should happen"? And I never see i = 10 when using debugger to step trace... In my code of the question, it just "always" gives me "i 10 should never happen".

Comment: It only occurs very rarely - you don't see it because it gets lost in all the other output. The code in the question _only_ produces output in the special case

Comment: @Hulk ok, you, joey and ivan are right, I didn't test it "long" enough!!